# Build array with different types

Tags: go

Can I build array what includes different types? For example:

```
[1, 2, "apple", true]
```

Comment: While there *are* ways to do this in Go, and perhaps there are valid use cases, I would recommend *not* doing this. It looks like you're trying to translate your Ruby knowledge and experience to Go, and this probably isn't a good idea. Go's typing is different from Ruby's, and requires a different way of thinking and programming.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks, I see what you mean, but I just wanna to know Go ability

Comment: If you are new to Go: Maybe it would be helpful to stick to "proper", safe and idiomatic Go and leave the borders of the Go universe unexplored for a few months?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by making a slice of `interface{}` type. For example:

```
func main() {
    arr := []interface{}{1, 2, "apple", true}
    fmt.Println(arr)

    // however, now you need to use type assertion access elements
    i := arr[0].(int)
    fmt.Printf("i: %d, i type: %T\n", i, i)

    s := arr[2].(string)
    fmt.Printf("b: %s, i type: %T\n", s, s)
}
```

Read more about this [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces).

Comment: "now you need to use type switches access elements" What you have there isn't a "type switch"; it's a type assertion.

Comment: @Tim: fixed. Thanks

Comment: To be precise it's a slice of same type - interface{}, not an array with different types elements.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation, you might be able to use a `struct` instead:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type array struct {
   one, two int
   fruit string
   truth bool
}

func main() {
   arr := array{1, 2, "apple", true}
   fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: The question clearly stated array, why use a struct?